# Why isn't my <a href working

Tags: javascript, php

I am using wordpress and I need to put my privacy policy in my footer. I managed to implement my "Disclosure" and "Disclaimer" as links but not my privacy policy. This is the code before my change:

```
    <div class="clearfix container">
        <div class="site-info">
            &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>. All rights reserved.    |     <a href="http://www.example.com/disclaimer">Disclaimer </a &#8226;
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
 <a href="http://www.example.com/disclosure">Disclosure </a abdf;
 </div>
```

And this is after:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="clearfix container">
        <div class="site-info">
            &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>. All rights reserved.    |     <a href="http://www.example.com/disclaimer">Disclaimer </a &#8226;
        </div><!-- .site-info -->

 <a href="http://www.example.com/disclosure">Disclosure </a abdf;

 <a href="http://www.example.com/privacy-policy">Privacy-Policy </a abdf;


    </div>
```

So I have "privacy policy" at my site but you cant click on it. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: why isn't your 'a' tag closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo when closing your a tags, you're missing the closing `>`'s;

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/disclosure">Disclosure</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/privacy-policy">Privacy-Policy</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is I'm noob and my disclosure was working well without ">" so I thought that my PP should be working as well.

Comment: It probably looked like it worked, but only because it was being closed by another element. If this answer has solved your problem, please accept it so the question is marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the closing tags for anchor tag

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/disclosure">Disclosure</a>
```

you missed `</a>`

Comment: Thank you, the thing is I'm noob and my disclosure was working well without ">" so I thought that my PP should be working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are the ones that close opened tags, it doesnt work by itself. But not closing, it could lead you to having hierachical problems. Child elements can mix up with parent elements and loose your layout completely.
In your case, disclosure link becomes a parent link because you have not closed the end tag for it. That is the reason first link is working and PP is getting mixed up with disclosure and lost an identity.

Hope this helps!!